# codeigniter, receiving no email after sending

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter email class and helper. Everything worked perfectly well just yesterday and I dont think that I have done anything with it, but now I just dont receive any emails. The print_debugger() is echoing that a mail has been successfully sent, but there is no email in my gmail inbox, nor is any in the spam.

I have also configured a James email server and I cant receive any emails on that too. I really dont know what to do. I read somewhere that maybe I had stated `$this->load->library('email')` multiple times, so I have deleted all that statements and instead of that I created an autoload function for that. There are no errors within the framework whatsoever but the emails just cant be received.

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('check@mail.com', 'Admin');
    $this->email->to('mygmailaccount@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('subject');
    $this->email->message('email body');

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

The output is something like this:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: sendmail
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sun, 14 Jul 2013 21:54:39 +0200
From: "Admin" 
Return-Path: 
To: mygmailaccount@gmail.com
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?subject?=
Reply-To: "check@mail.com" 
X-Sender: check@mail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <51e301ffa45d3@mail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

email body

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by looking in the mail server logs on the mail server that is being used to send the outgoing message from your codeignitor script.  These should show you (a) whether or not the outgoing mail server is receiving the message for queuing from your codeignitor script, and if so - (b) what is happening when delivery of the message to the remote MTA is attempted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Funny thing happened, i restarted my mac and got like 300 mails then :-/ I don't know where exactly was the problem but the restart did it.